# Limitar el tiempo en un formulario html y php

Tags: php, html

¿En un formulario html y php, que pasa a una db mysql, se puede evitar que un mismo usuario responda varias veces? ¿Y limitar el tiempo a una semana, por ej.? Quiero que después de un tiempo dado, un mes, (en el ejemplo el mes de febrero), el usuario ya no pueda cubrir el formulario y se cierre el mismo.

```
<?php
//prueba para limitar la fecha
if (date("m") >=2 && date ("m")<=3);
{
echo "has llegado tarde para cubrir el formulario";
}
else {
    exit;
}
?>
```

pero tengo un error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\procesaCasaTum.php on line 7

Comment: Hola,claro que se puede limitar , se puede hacer de todo cuando programas, Te recomiendo que formules mejor tu pregunta, puesto que no esta muy clara, y si quieres código, pues lo menos que la comunidad espera es que tu también nos compartas lo que tengas. Saludos

Comment: Las dos cosas se pueden hacer, lo que hace falta es que re formules tu pregunta y te centres en uno de los dos problemas. Si tienes algo de código, por favor colócalo para poderte ayudar, así como la parte de la bd donde vas a guardar los datos.

Comment: Si podemos restringir a un usuario conteste más de una vez, el problema es que deberás identificar al usuario en la base de datos, con esto refiero a que debe haber un login previo. Puedes limitar el tiempo del formulario muy fácil pero necesitamos que pongas el código que tengas.

Comment: @JuanCarlos para solucionar ese error, hay que eliminar el `;` al final de la línea del `if`

Comment: Se cierra el formulario pero no aparece el mensaje de por qué se cierra: "has llegado tarde para cubrir el formulario". Y el mensaje tendría que aparecer.

Comment: Si el usuario cubre el formulario dentro del mes de plazo, se envía el formulario y aparece el mensaje "has llegago tarde...". Si lo quiere enviarlo fuera de plazo, se cierra cierra el formulario pero sin el mensaje !

Answer (score 1):

El error que se esta dando en la linea 7 es debido a que estas usando un **(;)** al final del ***if***, te dejo el código corregido:

```
if (date("m") >=2 && date ("m")<=3){
    echo "has llegado tarde para cubrir el formulario";
}else {
    exit;
}
```